# How to deny access for fetch operations

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm trying to create an access control system at the document level in Meteor, and I seem to be missing how to prevent users from fetching documents.

I've read the documentation around `collection.allow` and `collection.deny`. Via these objects we can control "who" can `update`, `remove` and `insert`. The problem is that Meteor doesn't seem to supply  similar functionality for `fetch` operations. *What is proper way to deny unauthorized users from reading documents?*

**Extra requirement:** this needs to happen server side so we don't leak documents to unauthorized users over the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to deny reads to collection data once it has arrived on the client. In theory, there's no way to actually enforce **anything** on the client because the user could modify the code. You can, however, enforce which documents get published.

A publish function can handle authorization rules of arbirtary complexity. Here's a simple example where we want to publish documents from the `Messages` collection only to users who are members of the given group:

```
Meteor.publish('messagesForGroup', function(groupId) {
  check(groupId, String);

  var group = Groups.findOne(groupId);

  // make sure we have a valid group
  if (!group)
    throw new Meteor.Error(404, 'Group not found');

  // make sure the user is a member
  if (!_.contains(group.members, this.userId))
    throw new Meteor.Error(403, 'You are not a member of the group');

  return Messages.find({groupId: groupId});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Remove `autopublish` package from your app.

2) Create your own publish and deny access to unauthorized users

```
Meteor.publish("userData", function () {
    if (this.userId) { // Check user authorized
        return MyCollection.find(); // Share data
    } else {
        this.ready(); // Share nothing
    }
});
```

Comment: Does `Meteor.publish` only affect `Meteor.subscribe` or does it also impact `MyCollection.findOne()` operations on the client side as well?

Comment: It will restrict sending data from server to client. `MyCollection.findOne()` and `MyCollection.find()` on client will search data in client db (minimongo) not in server db. But if no data on client both this functions have no access to `MyCollection` data.